# dispatch_group_async function in swift 3.0

Tags: swift, swift3

My question is how to correctly translate this function in Swift 3 because i noticed there is a lot of documentation about `dispatch_async` but there isn't anything about `dispatch_group_async`

```
dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) { [unowned self] in
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd discourage the `[unowned self]` pattern, as that's a very dangerous practice. You only use `unowned` if you know that the closure cannot ever be called if `self` is deallocated, which is not the case here. If you need it, use `[weak self]`, but don't use `[unowned self]` in this scenario.

Comment: @Rob Thanks, i didn't know!

Comment: @Rob It is unrelated but what are the case where i have to use `[weak self] in` ? Because i have seen `[unowned self]` in lots of stackoverflow's replies.. that's why i used it. Can i access `self` correctly without any statement?

Comment: One generally uses `[weak self]` to resolve strong reference cycles (which isn't applicable here; there is no such cycle in this case). You also use `[weak self]` if you don't want to keep a strong reference to `self`. For example, imagine a view controller (VC) that initiates some time consuming process which updates the VC's outlet upon completion... but if the VC was dismissed in the intervening period of time, there is no point in hanging on to a VC that has been dismissed solely to update an outlet that is no longer visible.

Comment: Ok, i have understood. Thanks !! You're great @Rob

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
    .async(group:group) { [unowned self] in
        // code
    }
```